# Groff - which fonts are loaded by default

Tags: fonts, groff

Is there a standard set of fonts that is loaded by groff by default? And is that order always the same for all environments? Is it documented somewherr (I could not find it)?

I can make an educated guess what is loaded on my system (Slackware 14.2), but I cannot distinguish exactly all fonts and name them. As far as I can see, the list would be:

```
 1    Palatino regular
 2    Palatino italic
 3    Palatino bold
 4    Palatino bold italic
 5    Palatino (again?)
 6    Courier
 7    Courier Italic
 8    Courier Bold
 9    Courier bold-italic
10-13 ???
14    A sans font bold
15    sans font bold italic
16    sans font italic
17    sans font regular
etcetera
```

I am looking for a way to generate a set of `.fp`'s that does not deviate too much from what is considered as standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically troff drove the CAT phototypesetter that mounted by default Agfa Times, Agfa Courier and Agfa Symbol, that was in the 70's. Fonts where film strips, FYI.

In the 80's troff was adjusted to use PostScript fonts. In those times, most PS printers had only Adobe Times, Adobe Helvetica, Adobe Courier and Adobe Symbol in the renderer firmware.

In the early 90's when James Clarke wrote GNU roff, he chose to continue using the same defaults in order not to break all the preexisting documents created in the previous 20 years or so. As Apple had been selling its 35 font LaserWriter since 86  (a clear demonstration of Steve Jobs absolute lack of typographical taste, btw. Avant Garde? Bookman? Puke), James Clarke included them as Groff's defaults. Later in the mid 90's when Artifex Software the producer of Ghostscript licensed URW Typographie 35 "standard" LW fonts clones and allowed it's use for non commercial purposes, the original Adobe font metrics were replaced by the URW ones in order to minimize legal liabilities with using proprietary data.

TLDR: The original CAT phototypesetter could only mount 10 font faces. The vendor gave you Times, Courier and Symbol and other font families were very, very expensive. The *roffs existing today maintain the original limitations because they either are the original, namely heirloom troff, or a faithful reproduction as far as it is possible while keeping with the times, namely groff.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Palopezv answer, it seems you can trust only font 1-13 to be the same. After some research, I found that the following font list is more-or-less standard:

```
1  times
2  times italic
3  times bold
4  times bold italic
5  times
6  courier
7  courier italic
8  courier bold
9  courier bold italic
10  symbol
11  symbol
12  symbol
13  symbol
14  avant garde bold
15  avant garde bold italic
16  avant garde italic
17  avant garde
18  bookman bold
19  bookman bold italic
20  bookman italic
21  bookman
22  helvetica bold
23  helvetica bold italic
24  helvetica italic
25  helvetica
26  helvetica condensed bold
27  helvetica condensed bold italic
28  helvetica condensed italic
29  helvetica condensed
```

30 and above differs; sometimes there are Cyrillic fonts, sometimes schoolbook, etc.